# The pages that ubuntu-sdk adds to Qt-Creator can't be zoomed

Tags: ubuntu-sdk, qt-creator, zooming

Ubuntu-SDK adds 5 buttons to the Qt-Creator toolbar (wiki, pastebin, irc, core apps and api). The sole function those buttons seem to have is to link to some web pages. Those pages can not be zoomed with the ctrl+mouse-wheel.
That is very uncomfortable for those of us that do not have a 20/20 vision.

How do I change the pages zoom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that zooming can't be done. Odd but true since I really don't know why they put copies of websites on your computer just to display in an micro font so you cant read a thing.

But thing don't always make sense. So I declare this question answered.